# android NDK(CMakeLists.txt) with c++11

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, c++11, android-ndk

Hi I'm making a face landmark detection app in ANDROID VERSION.

I'm using Android Studio 2.3(NDK SUPPORT) 
So far so good except build.gradle & CMakeLists.txt setting

CMakeList.txt

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```

build.grale

```
defaultConfig {
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions -std=c++11"
            arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
        }
    }
```

Like above, I have a error like 
**linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

How can I use standard c+11 without Android.mk, Application.mk file

Comment: Since you're getting a linker error (did you try using `-v` to get more information?), is there any particular reason why you think this is related to the `-std=c++11` flag?

Comment: You can find the exact commands that are performed to build your C++ in .externalNativeBuild folder

Comment: What's the actual error?